# php in body -- missing something obvious

Tags: php

My PHP is not PHPing, so made simple test... must be missing something obvious.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <?php echo '<script language=\"javascript\">confirm("Do you see this?")</script>;'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

In code body, I get:   `confirm("Do you see this?");'; ?>`

---

When I "View Source", I see:

`<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo '<script language=\"javascript\">confirm("Do you see this?")</script>;'; ?>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Can you show the exact source code and/or "view source" result you are getting?

Comment: Why are you escaping the "? Dont think there is a need to.

Comment: Has your file the right extension (in most cases .php) and is your server configured correctly for php?

Comment: Thanks guys for editing the code block -- I'm also having trouble inserting code into these questions. I wrote the intro sentence, then clicked the code-insert braces, then copy/pasted formatted code. After posting the question, only the same RESULT I indicated above (after the code block) appeared in the post. Why would that be?

Comment: And also remove ; after closing script tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what extension has your file? is a webserver running? how are you calling your php script?

make sure it has a `.php` extension, the webserver is running, the file resides under the webroot directory and you call it via `http://localhosti/path/to/file.php`

also make sure you don't escape quotation marks when not needed, `echo '<script type="text/javascript">…</script>';` should do the job

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the backslashes from the `\"javascript\"`.

```
<?php echo '<script language="javascript">confirm("Do you see this?")</script>;'; ?>
```

In PHP you can put strings in single `'` or double `"` quotes. This is quite hard to explain (and/or understand) in a few lines, so here's a few valid ways to write down a string containing quotes:

```
echo 'This has "double quotes"...';
echo 'This has \'single quotes\'...';
echo "This has \"double quotes\"...";
echo "This has 'single quotes'...";
```

There are many more subtleties to this, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks - there were several things wrong with my code, but the primary one was thinking that if a page starts with HTML, it should have the HTML extension. Thanks very much for your help, though -- the escaped quotes around "javascript" were also a problem, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the \ from the double quotes and the extra semi colon

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <?php echo '<script language="javascript">confirm("Do you see this?")</script>'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're right, there was an extra semi-colon (copied directly from the example) and the quotes around javascript did not need to be escaped, as you identified. However, the show-stopper was the incorrect file extension.